# Why python throws an "ImportError: No module named linkextractor" even if the Scrapy module already installed?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, pip, virtualenv

I want to install [portia](https://github.com/scrapinghub/portia). It requires `scrapy` and `slybot`.
I also installed `virtualenv` (as recommended) and executed `virtualenv Portia` to create a python virtual environment only for this project. Now it requires to start `twisted` server with `twistd -n slyd`, but then it throws an Error:

```
  File "/home/john/Downloads/portia-master/slybot/slybot/linkextractor/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .base import BaseLinkExtractor, ALLOWED_SCHEMES   File "/home/john/Downloads/portia-master/slybot/slybot/linkextractor/base.py", line 6, in <module>
    from scrapy.linkextractor import IGNORED_EXTENSIONS ImportError: No module named linkextractor
```

I have Ubuntu 12.04, installed: `python 2.7, pip, python-scrapy, python-twisted`

What could be here wrong? I didn't use `pip` and `virtualenv` before, does seem something wrong with the deployment workflow (e.g. ENVIRONMENT variables, other `virtualenv/pip` configurations) I described above?

Answer (score 3):

In python3, just add `s` to the end of `linkextractor`.

Replace :

```
from scrapy.linkextractor import LinkExtractor
```

with :

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
                         ^
```

and enjoy it.

for more information read the Scrapy documentation from [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html).

Answer (score 0):

It misses out the middle part; `contrib`, of which `linkextractor` is a submodule.

It is supposed to be:

```
scrapy.contrib.linkextractor
       ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I didn't edit the code, just want to play with it. There are no issues related to wrong imports name on the github projects. Will try it now

Comment: @static Are you sure that you have the exact same dependency versions as the github code does?

Comment: actually it is not from the project, it is from the Scrapy project, they have also there `from scrapy.linkextractor import IGNORED_EXTENSIONS`

Comment: @static There is no such thing as `scrapy.linkextractor`. Check the documentation for scrapy.

Comment: when I changed it as you proposed it returned actually the same: `from scrapy.contrib.linkextractor import IGNORED_EXTENSIONS
ImportError: No module named linkextractor`

Comment: @static I am getting my information from [this](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/linkextractor.py).

Comment: hi Alex!
Would you mind giving a help on this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630771/scrapy-linkextractor-duplicating

Answer (score -2):

Well, I think that you should see this issue (https://github.com/scrapinghub/portia/issues/13) in github scrapinhub repo.

I solved some errors with imports installing the libraries in my system instead of in virtualenv.

In my case, the libraries were jsonschema (`pip install jsonschema`), and slybot (`pip install -e slybot`), and after I ran requirements.txt.

Best regards!